# Possible problem with country and language tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm not sure about this, so I'm posting it here. We have some tags that also have language tags. e.g: [germany](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) and [german](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) we also have a [french](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/french) tag. Should this kind of tagging be allowed? I do believe that a tag like [latin](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin) and [rome](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rome) are ok, because latin is a way broader subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO it should be Germany and German-Language, France and french-language, Rome and Latin-languange (this is the odd one, but it's best to keep the same pattern).  You then have Spain and Spanish-language, etc.

Comment: I kinda prefer this route, too. It makes it clear what it means, and if you just type the name of the language (which, so far, has been conveniently equivalent to the adjective for that country), you'll get the language tag as a suggestion.

Comment: Sounds good! :D